# WPF Datagrid - How to validate multiple rows and mark all invalid ones?

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a datagrid with rows where the validation depends on his siblings. So far I'm using BindingGroups and a custom ValidationRule to validate multiple rows a the same time. But I can't figure out how to change the appereance of the invalid row entries. I return a ValidationResult and my grid gets a red border but my style gets ignored.

My xaml style code so far:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F6B39E"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

edit: maybe I should post a little more of my code
at the moment I have this validation declaration:

```
 <dg:DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
      <viewModel:StreamGridValidationRules />
 </dg:DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

With this code my style above gets set correctly, but only one row gets validated at a time. As I need to validate all siblings and his parent aswell, I changed my code to this:

```
<dg:DataGrid.BindingGroup>
     <BindingGroup Name="BindingGroup">
         <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
              <viewModel:StreamGridValidationRules />
          </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
     </BindingGroup>
</dg:DataGrid.BindingGroup>
```

With this I get multiple items in the BindingGroup but my style gets ignored completly and the grid just gets the standard 1px red border.

Thanks beforehand for any tips and hints!

tS!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you are setting the BindingGroup and what mechanism you are using in your custom ValidationRule to validate multiple rows at once?  The XAML/code that creates the BindingGroup and the essential portions of the custom ValidationRule would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you remove the x:Key="RowStyle", does it work then?

forgive me if im being obvious, but not seeing the rest of your code, i cant tell. If you are naming a style it wont get used unless you are explicitly setting it to be used.

Comment: I'm setting the RowStyle on the datagrid (RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}), but your right, I can remove it on both sides.